# How can I add exceptions for grep -l command?

Tags: grep

It's easy to perform a simple `grep -l <pattern> <file_name>`, where `<file_name>` will be returned if `<file_name>` has at least one line with `<pattern>`.

I want just to add an `<exception_pattern>` pattern, wherein `<file_name>` is returned if it has at least one line with `<pattern>` but should no return if it has at least one line with `<exception_pattern>`.

Example:

```
$ cat file1
Results: 1, 2, 3
OK

$ cat file2
Results: 1, 2, 3
NOK

$ grep -l Results file1
file1

$ grep -l Results file2
file2

$ grep -l Results -exception NOK file1
file1

$ grep -l Results -exception NOK file2
$
$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU tools:

```
grep -lZe Results -- "${files[@]}" | xargs -r0 grep -Le NOK --
```

with `$files` the array holding the list of file names.

`-L` (aka `--files-without-match`) is a GNU extension that prints the names of the files without match (and can be successfully read). So that first `grep` builds the list of files that contain `Results` and `xargs` passes those as arguments to the second `grep` which then reports among those the ones that don't contain `NOK`.

To get the list result into another array, in `bash` 4.4+, you'd do:

```
readarray -td '' matching_files < <(
  grep -lZe Results -- "${files[@]}" | xargs -r0 grep -LZe NOK --
)
```

(the important bit being to use NUL-delimited records to pass a list of files between commands)

In `zsh`:

```
matching_files=( ${(0)"$(
  grep -lZe Results -- $files | xargs -r0 grep -LZe NOK --
)"} )
```

For a single file, standardly, you can always do:

```
grep -q Results file1 && ! grep -q NOK file1 && echo file1
```

Or for an arbitrary file path (other than `-` which `grep` interprets specially as meaning stdin instead of the file called `-`):

```
grep -qe Results -- "$file" &&
  ! grep -qe NOK -- "$file" &&
  printf '%s\n' "$file"
```